# Looking for a more efficient way of creating this overflow hidden and translate animation on text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Recently i have been trying to create an animation effect, where i use overflow hidden on a parent span, then tranforming it into view. My current code seems a little bit complicated, and im wondering if theres any other way around it, considering its an effect im going to use a lot throughout the website.

```js
    $(".in1").addClass("error").delay(125).queue(function(next){
        $(this).addClass('in1-active');
    });
    $(".in2").addClass("error").delay(250).queue(function(next){
        $(this).addClass('in2-active');
    });
    $(".in3").addClass("error").delay(375).queue(function(next){
        $(this).addClass('in3-active');
    });
```

```css
.inwrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.in1, .in2, .in3{
    display: block;
    transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0,1,.82,1);
    transform: translateY(101%);
}
.in1-active, .in2-active , .in3-active  {
    display: block;
    transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="introduction">
  <h2>
    <span class="inwrap"><span class="in1"><a href="#about-me">Graphic designer</a> that </span></span>
    <span class="inwrap"><span class="in2">specializes in <a href="#days-of-ux">interactive</a></span></span>
    <span class="inwrap"><span class="in3"> design and <a href="#struggle-magazine">print</a></span></span>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to handle separate click. You can use wild card and handle all click on single.

```js
$('[class^=in]').addClass("error").delay(125).queue(function(next) {
  var cls = $(this).attr('class');
  cls = cls + "-active";
  $(this).addClass(cls);
});
```

```css
.inwrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.in {
    display: block;
    transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0,1,.82,1);
    transform: translateY(101%);
}
.in-active{
    display: block;
    transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="introduction">
  <h2>
    <span class="inwrap"><span class="in1"><a href="#about-me">Graphic designer</a> that </span></span>
    <span class="inwrap"><span class="in2">specializes in <a href="#days-of-ux">interactive</a></span></span>
    <span class="inwrap"><span class="in3"> design and <a href="#struggle-magazine">print</a></span></span>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: The code snipped isnt working. Something im missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Found out a way by using setTimeout instead.

```js
    $('.in').each(function(i){
        var row = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
              row.addClass('in-active');
          }, 150*i);

    });
```

```css
.inwrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.in {
    display: block;
    transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0,1,.82,1);
    transform: translateY(101%);
}
.in-active{
    display: block;
    transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="introduction">
  <h2>
    <span class="inwrap"><span class="in"><a href="#about-me">Graphic designer</a> that </span></span>
    <span class="inwrap"><span class="in">specializes in <a href="#days-of-ux">interactive</a></span></span>
    <span class="inwrap"><span class="in"> design and <a href="#struggle-magazine">print</a></span></span>
  </h2>
</div>
```